# Changing file permissions of unowned files in linux

Tags: linux, file

I've written some code in C that needs to change a file modification time using utime(), 
but I get permission error.

Is there a way changing file permissions even though I'm don't own the file?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, be root. Linux by default doesn't have a fine-grained security model. Either you're root and have all rights, or you're a regular user and have only rights to your own stuff.

Comment: Or you are a member of one of the groups that has permissions on the file.  The default security model has 3 levels, not just 2.

Comment: Who uses groups nowadays? But it's true, yes.

Comment: So how is it that I can use rename() to place the file in a different folder but keeping the existing file name?  I do not get permission errors.

Comment: IIRC that's a directory operation, not a file operation, and then the directory permissions instead of the file permissions are used.

Comment: I'm loading a shared library like this: export LD_PRELOAD ="/home/test/wrapper-debug.so".  Is there way to load the library as root?

Comment: @Smithy: No, Linux processes run as a single user (Windows can do impersonation, but not on a module level. Only at thread level)